# How should I handle an error in libpq for postgresql

Tags: c++, postgresql, error-handling, libpq

I'm creating a few simple helper classes and methods for working with libpq, and am wondering if I receive an error from the database - (e.g. SQL error), how should I handle it?

At the moment, each method returns a bool depending on whether the operation was a success, and so is up to the user to check before continuing with new operations.

However, after reading the libpq docs, if an error occurs the best I can come up with is that I should log the error message / status and otherwise ignore. For example, if the application is in the middle of a transaction, then I believe it can still continue (Postgresql won't cancel the transaction as far as I know).

Is there something I can do with PostgreSQL / libpq to make the consequences of such errors safe regarding the database server, or is ignorance the better policy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should examine the `SQLSTATE` in the error and make handling decisions based on that *and that alone*. Never try to make decisions in code based on the error message text.

An application should simply retry transactions for certain kinds of errors:

- Serialization failures
- Deadlock detection transaction aborts

For connection errors, you should reconnect then re-try the transaction.

Of course you want to set a limit on the number of retries, so you don't loop forever if the issue doesn't clear up.

Other kinds of errors aren't going to be resolved by trying again, so the app should report an error to the client. Syntax error? Unique violation? Check constraint violation? Running the statement again won't help.

There is [a list of error codes in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) but the docs don't explain much about each error, but the preamble is quite informative.

On a side note: One trap to avoid falling into is "testing" connections with a trivial query before using them, and assuming that means the real query can't fail. That's a race condition. Don't bother testing connections; simply run the real query and handle any error.

The details of what exactly to do depend on the error and on the application. If there was a single always-right answer, libpq would already do it for you.

My suggestions:

- Always keep a record of the transaction until you've got a confirmed commit from the DB, in case you have to re-run. Don't just fire-and-forget SQL statements.
- Retry the transaction without a disconnect and reconnect for SQLSTATEs `40001` (serialization_failure) and `40P01` (deadlock_detected), as these are transient conditions generally resolved by re-trying. You should log them, as they're opportunities to improve how the app interacts with the DB and if they happen a lot they're a performance problem.
- Disconnect, reconnect, and retry the transaction at least once for error class `08` (connection exceptions).
- Handle `53300` (too_many_connections) and `53400` (connection limit exceeded) with specific and informative errors to the user. Same with the other `53` class entries.
- Handle class `57`'s entries with specific and informative errors to the user. Do not retry if you get a `query_cancelled` (57014), it'll make sysadmins very angry.
- Handle `25006` (read_only_sql_transaction) by reporting a different error, telling the user you tried to write to a read-only database or using a read-only transaction.
- Report a different error for `23505` (UNIQUE violation), indicating that there's a conflict in a unique constraint or primary key constraint. There's no point retrying.
- Error class `01` should never produce an exception.
- Treat other cases as errors and report them to the caller, with details from the problem - most importantly `SQLSTATE`. Log all the details if you return a simplified error.

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Lots of detailed info to parse and work into my code, it's very useful!

Comment: Can we get "class 08" error code  from PQresultErrorField function for database unavailable and database disconnection scenarios  ?